# CSS navbar dropdown isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bulma

I'm trying to code dropdown menus for Bulma's navigation bar, but it seems to be having issues right now, can anyone help me find out why?

```
<nav class="nav has-shadow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-left">
            <a class="navbar-item is-tab is-active" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/">Home</a> <a class="navbar-item is-tab" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/">Profile</a> <a class="navbar-item is-tab" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/customize/">Education</a> <a class="navbar-item is-tab" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/classes/">Skills</a> <a class="navbar-item is-tab" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/modular/">Housing</a> <a class="navbar-item is-tab" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/modular/">Activity</a>
            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable" style="margin-left: auto; display: inline-flex;">
                <a class="navbar-link"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp; Dave Fox</a>
                <div class="navbar-dropdown" style="left: initial; right: 0;">
                    <div class="navbar-item">
                        <div>
                            <small><a href="/account/language">Account Settings - Language</a></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Here are my JS files:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://holorp.com/assets/bulma/0.5.0/js/bulma.js"></script>
<script src="https://holorp.com/assets/holorp/2.1/js/holorp.js"></script>
```

and then I'm just using the default Bulma CSS

Comment: Can you be more specific than "not working"?

Comment: If you actually read the question, it explains everything in there. I've attached an animated image showing exactly how its not working.

Comment: Attached images are not helpful to future readers of this question as the link will die.  A written description is preferred on SO.

Comment: So that isn't something that I should do, its something that is preferred? I prefer not to, thank you. I think an image definitely best describes it.

Comment: I can't see the image as it is on imgur and my firewall blocks that site as being adult content - that is why all the details should be self contained within the question.  Also, if you are going to be petulant expect to get no help.  Besides without a clear problem statement, your question is off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this JavaScript?

I use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Hover your mouse below the text below</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Here!</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```